# ¿Como agrupar varios valores iguales que vienen dentro de un array en php?

Tags: php, sql

Buen dia, Tengo un arreglo ($array) en el cual trae varios productos con la cantidad existente en un inventario. Mi problema es que varios productos son los mismos pero la cantidad es diferente y yo quiero hacer que si el producto se repite mas de una vez simplemente me sume la cantidad de todos estos y me imprima solo una vez. 
Ejemplo Problema:

1. Tienda A = Arroz = 1
2. Tienda A = Arroz = 1
3. Tienda B = Lentejas =2
4. Tienda B =Arroz = 2
5. Tienda A =Arroz = 4
6. Tienda B =Arroz = 1

Lo ideal es que esos productos los sumara y los agrupara para verlos de la siguiente manera:

Ejemplo Solución:

1. Tienda A =Arroz = 6
2. Tienda A =Lentejas = 2
3. Tienda B =Arroz = 3

Comment: Por lo que dices, supongo que el array está en PHP. ¿Podrías mostrar un ejemplo de cómo vienen los datos en él?  También conviene que digas dónde y cómo se genera ese array, por si se puede mejorar algo en la lógica que estás implementando y de ese modo simplificar el código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno bro tu caso se resuelve desde el mismo query que retorna el array, y es que debes sumar y agrupar los elementos, algo así:

```
SELECT tienda, producto, SUM(ventas) as total FROM ventas GROUP BY tienda,producto
```

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE ventas (
  tienda VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  producto VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  ventas VARCHAR(50)
);
INSERT INTO ventas VALUES ('valencia','arroz','10');
INSERT INTO ventas VALUES ('valencia','arroz','15');
INSERT INTO ventas VALUES ('valencia','pasta','8');
INSERT INTO ventas VALUES ('valencia','pasta','4');
INSERT INTO ventas VALUES ('caracas','pasta','12');
INSERT INTO ventas VALUES ('caracas','arroz','12');
INSERT INTO ventas VALUES ('caracas','arroz','14');
INSERT INTO ventas VALUES ('caracas','arroz','34');
INSERT INTO ventas VALUES ('valencia','arroz','5');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT tienda, producto, SUM(ventas) as total FROM ventas GROUP BY tienda,producto
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c7e55/2/0)**:

```
|   tienda | producto | total |
|----------|----------|-------|
|  caracas |    arroz |    60 |
|  caracas |    pasta |    12 |
| valencia |    arroz |    30 |
| valencia |    pasta |    12 |
```

Te dejo una muestra funcionando:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c7e55/2

Comment: Me parece una mala idea lo que recomiendas en esta respuesta: repetir una y otra vez en la tabla `ventas` el nombre de la tienda. Esa tabla debería recibir más bien un `id_tienda`. Lo que sugieres no aplica el modelo relacional, cuando haya millones de ventas, habrá millones de varchar con `valencia,valencia,valencia,millones de valencia` en lugar de millones de `ID`. Eso se notará en el tamaño de la BD y en la rapidez de las consultas. Además, habrá quizá unos cientos de `valncia, valenci ...` y errores similares muy difíciles de detectar y normalizar.

Comment: @A.Cedano entiendo lo que comenta pero decir que es mala idea lo que propongo es querer ser muy intelectual cuando no se es, la respuesta es válida para la pregunta que se esta haciendo, el individuo en cuestión no ha informado ni dado detalles de su estructura de tablas ni menos si las mismas están o no relacionadas, la pregunta fue concreta así como la respuesta. si ves claramente aun cuando se normaliza las tablas el resultado es el mismo, porque se requiere de una segunda agrupación que es por producto.

Comment: @A.Cedano ahora bien si detallamos lo que comentas y tenemos una tabla de tiendas que seria lo mas justo este asociaría los productos del inventario a un código de tienda en dicha tabla, ya luego cuando quieras verificar el inventario por tienda y agrupado por producto, sucedería lo mismo, se repetiría el código de la tienda asociada tantas veces como productos esta tenga, en todo caso, muestra tu solución y te diré si no es lo mismo que esta aquí o no.

Comment: No sé qué quieres decir con *querer ser muy intelectual cuando no se es*.  Sugerir un modelo de datos en el que repites sin más nombres de tiendas como de productos es una muy muy muy pésima práctica. Creo que este sitio no debe existir solamente para resolver problemas puntuales, sino para sugerir a veces cambios más profundos. Eso los usuarios suelen agradecerlo porque les abre nuevos horizontes. En este caso es evidente que se debe al menos proponer una mejor organización de los datos. Luego él hará lo que quiera, pero no viene mal hacer aquí una crítica constructiva.

Comment: Lee el comentario que hice en su pregunta. Yo no me voy a aventurar en una respuesta cuando entiendo que el problema está a otro nivel, que podría ser precisamente el modelo de datos. Mi propuesta en ese sentido es simple. Las siguientes tablas: `tienda, producto, venta`  ... y relacionar los datos mediante `IDs`, no mediante campos varchar. No importa cuantas tablas haya, y para `inventario`  se podría aplicar la misma lógica. En los casos que se requiera se pueden usar tablas asociativas o pivote (como las llaman algunos). No se repetiría ningún varchar, solo los `IDs`.

Comment: @A.Cedano si desea hacer dicha critica constructiva puede hacerlo realizando la respuesta correspondiente con la respuesta a la pregunta y la sugerencia al modelo de datos que propone, en cuyo caso no he dicho que sea o no la respuesta, es evidente que se debe normalizar un sistema de tablas para esto, pues debe tener tablas para tiendas, productos, inventario, ventas, etc. Incluso si la respuesta que cuelgues aqui es sumamente mejor que la mía la voy a votar, la idea es ayudarnos y ayudar a la persona que pregunta, la pregunta fue como agrupo ese array que llega y la respuesta es esa.

Comment: Su pregunta tiene poca información para aportar una respuesta. Supongamos que el OP tiene bien su modelo de datos, que tiene las tablas relacionadas correctamente por sus columnas `ID` respectivas. La respuesta que tú aportas lo que hará será despistarlo, animarle a crear un modelo de datos que viola de manera flagrante el modelo de datos relacional. Por eso mi crítica a tu respuesta y por eso la votaré negativamente. El modelo de datos correcto sería este: `CREATE TABLE ventas (
  id_tienda INT NOT NULL,
  id_producto INT NOT NULL,
  cantidad INT
);`

Comment: Un ejemplo de inserción sería: `INSERT INTO ventas VALUES (1,2,10);`, donde `1` sería el id de la tienda `valencia` y `2` sería el id del producto `arroz` ... Puede que este modelo deba ser ampliado, añadiendo un id para unidad de medida por ejemplo: libras, kilos, gramos, metros  o incluyendo en producto una categoría por la que se sepa en qué medidas se expresa ese producto... y muchas más cosas.  La obtención de datos se haría uniendo cada tabla por su `id` mediante `JOIN`  y agrupado datos.

Comment: @A.Cedano no se preocupe, usted es libre de Votar como lo desee, esa es la libertad que tenemos en el mundo, no voy a perder el sueño ni voy a dejar de ganar dinero, y lo que comentas estas en lo cierto, ahora te invito a que uses el sqlfinddle y crees dicho modelo de datos con la salida a informe y me digas en que punto no repites el nombre de la tienda en cuestión, pues la id de la tienda no va al informe, al fin y al cabo, esperemos la respuesta de la persona que pregunta y vemos como va. Saludos

Comment: Veo que el OP aceptó tu respuesta porque al parecer resolvió su problema. Si él lo ha dado por bueno OK, de todos modos yo mantengo el voto negativo y los comentarios porque me parece que el problema así no queda resuelto de raíz. Que conste que no tengo nada contra ti, pero sí contra tu respuesta por los motivos que ya expuse. La intención de los comentarios es solamente para que conste que, aunque el OP haya aceptado la respuesta, no es un modelo a imitar. Tampoco escribiré una respuesta si la persona que pregunta no se interesa por enfocar el problema desde otro ámbito.

Comment: @A.Cedano dale bro, no hay problema, como ya te dije, tienes y gozas de esa libertad, no me molesta en realidad, entiendo lo que comentas y estoy claro en lo que propones, pero mi respuesta fue directa para la pregunta directa del amigo, si el necesitaba profundizar mas allá, con gusto le doy la cátedra, pero no era el caso.